# Isomorphisms between $C([a,b])$ and some subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-space-isomorphism

Let us denote by $U$ the following subspace of $C^{1}[a, b]$ :
$$
U=\left\{f \in C^{1}[a, b]: f(a)=0\right\}
$$
and with $W$ the following subspace of $C^{1}[a, b]:$
$$
W=\left\{f \in C^{1}[a, b]: f=\text{const on }[a, b]\right\}.
$$
I want to show the following isomorphisms of vector spaces:
$ (a) \quad C[a, b]\cong U\\
(b) \quad C[a, b] \cong C^{1}[a, b] / W.
$

Any hints are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not all infinite dimensional spaces are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Dimensions are not useful at all. For a) consider the map $f \mapsto \int_a^{x}f(t)dt$. Verify that this map is linear, one-to-one and onto.

For b) consider the equivalence class of a function $f\in C^{1}([a,b])/W$. Map this to the derivative $f'$. Check that  this is linear , one-to-one and onto. [Recall that $f'=g'$ implies that $f-g \in W$].

Comment: I don't see why the first map is linear. $f(x+y)\neq f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(\lambda x)\neq \lambda f(x)$. Because why should $F(x)$ be linear?

Comment: That is not the definition of linearity. Linearity means $\int_a^{x} [cf(t)+dg(t)]dt=c\int_a^{x} f(t)dt+d\int_a^{x} g(t)dt$ **for all $x$**. @calculatormathematical

Comment: I think a much clearer way to write this map is as $f\mapsto \int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$, if this is what you intended.